# angularjs update variable information on query

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular

I need to update a variable called `$user`very often.

Is it the best approach to send a query to the server every x seconds (it contains userdata) or is it actually possible to send a query / update it on every other POST request I make with angularjs?

What would the best way to update it from the server be?

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 0):

If you have the liberty to modify the API code, then best is to use signalR (for ASP.Net webAPI) or Socket.io (for node js).

Otheriwise polling with $timeout is the only option as far as I know.

Comment: How would you suggest the socket.io would be?